# How do find out which Log Analytics Workspace has the Subscription Level Activity Log,Azure ADAudit Log,SignIn Log

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-log-analytics

How do find out which Log Analytics Workspace has the Subscription Level Activity Log,Azure AD Audit Log,Sign In Log.
Is there any api or kql query?

Answer (score 0):

As you aware you have the ability to forward your Azure AD logs to Azure Log Analytics and there you can query. But in order to know in which Log analytics workspace has this Azure AD logs or Activity logs is moved is not available currently. Kindly look into this  [documents](https://github.com/AzureAD/Deployment-Plans/tree/master/Log%20Analytics%20Views).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to understand the reason or use case for your requirement. However, to accomplish your requirement, you would have to write a small shell script with below steps.

1. Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces/list) REST API and get all the Log Analytics workspace in a subscription.
2. Store the output in an array
3. Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/get) REST API to separately query count of "AzureActivity", "AuditLogs" and "SigninLogs" tables i.e., in {query} section of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/get) 1st REST API give "AzureActivity | count" and similarly give "AuditLogs | count" and "SigninLogs | count" for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query/get) 2nd and 3rd REST API's.
4. Query the 3 REST API(s) that are explained in above step #3 for all the Log Analytics workspaces (that are part of output from above step #2) separately and in succession.
5. Store the output of which Log Analytics workspace has the Subscription Level Activity Log (based on AzureActivity table's count being > 0), Azure AD Audit Log (based on AuditLogs table's count being > 0), SignIn Log (based on SigninLogs table's count being > 0).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to know. Get into Log Analytics UI from one of the workspaces and change its scope to the subscription scope. See explanation here: https://youtu.be/34IrPO1Xh2o

Now you can query all records that are associated with this subscription.
The workspace ID BTW appears as "TenantId"
Meir